# При генерации некоторые значения повторяются

Tags: c++

Я написал функцию для генерации строки из рандомных символов

```
std::string gen()
{
    std::string all = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int allLen = all.size();
    std::string symbols;
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++)
    {
        symbols += all[rand() % allLen];
    }
    std::cout << "GEN:\t" << symbols << std::endl;
    return symbols;
}
```

Но на выходе я получаю

```
GEN:    Be3y2AiFa7
GEN:    E1faOVvYuT
GEN:    E1faOVvYuT
GEN:    E1faOVvYuT
GEN:    E1faOVvYuT
GEN:    E1faOVvYuT
GEN:    HNnhlq7KiJ
```

А мне нужно что бы каждый раз выдавало рандомное значение, как я могу это сделать?

Comment: вызывайте `srand` только один раз при старте программы

Comment: https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25

Comment: Используйте `<random>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция `srand` задает начальное значение `seed` для алгоритма генератора псевдослучайных чисел.

Если ей на вход подавать одно и тоже значение, то последовательность чисел, выдаваемых функцией `rand` так же будет одинаковая.

В данном случае в качестве инициализации используется текущая временная метка(`time(0)`)

Ошибка состоит в том, что функция `srand` вызывается многократно(при каждом вызове `gen`)

Тем самым если вызывать функцию `gen` в цикле, то значение `time(0)` не будет успевать меняться и генератор чисел будет сбрасываться на одну и туже последовательность.

Решение: функцию `srand` нужно вызывать только один раз при старте программы.

Comment: если `srand` вызывать при старте программы, то после последующего `fork` последовательности псевдослучайных чисел тоже могут совпадать у родителя и ребенка